# How do I pass in a string to get populated by getJSON's function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson

I'd like to do something like:

```
var content = "";
$.getJSON("/plants", function(result) {
    $.each(result.plants), function() {
        content += "<tr><td>"+this.plant_name+"</td></tr>";
    });
});
$("#plant_table").append(content);
```

By the time I do the append at the last line, `content` is empty. I'd guess it's because of the scope of the `content` variable, but I'm unfamiliar with how to remedy this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: put last line in callback

Comment: put last line in callback as **dandavis** said, and check `console.log(result)` - maybe your script returns nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @dandavis and probably the other person who I just see answered this said, try:

```
var content = "";
$.getJSON("/plants", function(result) {
    $.each(result.plants), function() {
        content += "<tr><td>"+this.plant_name+"</td></tr>";
    });
    $("#plant_table").append(content);
});
```

The $.getJSON is non-blocking / asynchronous, thus your .append() is occurring prior to $.getJSON() succeeding and manipulating the variable named *content*.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the content $("#plant_table").append(content); in getJSON function.
Because if the content is out of getJSON function, it is ran firstly.
It is synchronize problem. :)